# How to pull out records fro a data frame where the ID has not changed but the status has changed from low to high or vice versa in python

Tags: python

from the below table I want to pull records with ID 1 and ID 3.

```
ID Status assigned
1  low     yes 
1  High    no
2  low     no
3  high    yes
3  low     yes
```

Please let me know in python how can this be done.

Comment: so you want to return ID appearing more than one time ?

Comment: from the above table I want to pull ID's where status has changed not considering the column assigned

Answer (score 0):

I can propose this solution. In your case, it's equivalent to get ID appearing twice or more so you can you use `groupby().count()`.

First : `grouped=df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).count()`

Then in `list_ID` you have IDs that have changed: `list_ID=grouped.loc[grouped['Status']>=2,'ID'].values.tolist()`

If you want the df with these IDs : `df.loc[df['ID'].isin(list_ID)]`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  data=df.groupby('id',as_index=False).count()
  status_change=grouped.loc[data['Status']>1,'id'].values
```

output

```
 [1, 3]
```